# Cross-Compile Setup for ARM on Linux or Cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, toolchain

I've been stuck for several days setting up a cross-compiler for ARM on Linux or Cygwin. I've found some links (e.g., https://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/19-arm-cross-compiling-howto.html) but they are out-dated or require a lot of steps to accomplish the job.

I need to compile C/C++ code to an ARM binary executed by QEMU, which is used by the ESESC architectural simulator. My host machine is an X86-64 remote cluster running Linux/CentOS.

I don't have root access permission, if that matters.

Comment: All I know is that ESESC uses the QEMU emulator to run ARM binaries. There is no OS for the target.

Answer (score 1):

When I built LFS (Linux from Scratch) for the Efika smartbook,  [this was the cross-compiler instructions I used](https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/127-personal/468920-cross-compiling-for-arm). Basically, any build tools, you compile into a new area with makefiles created with "./configure --target=arm-linux". You can then compile with arm-linux-gcc and even have that compiler option in code::blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was so helpful. Where to find patch-2.6.35-rmk4.gz?

Comment: I found links to (almost) all the components I needed in the books on the Linux from scratch site (http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/download.html). 
LFS is basically a book of instructions which contains links to all the packages and patches needed. The patch you are looking for is probably specific to a particular release and is now incorporated into the kernel. It's probably worth downloading LFS and then bringing in all the latest packages.

Comment: Not sure how long this link will remain, but the patch-2.6.35 i found here: http://ftp.naist.jp/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/testing/v2.6.35/ there are other patches there too. Presumably rc4 is the one we need.